# matrix warning in R

Tags: r, matrix, warnings

I have two elements in a workspace `rr` and `ll` (two matrices)

I do

```
Warning message:
In cbind(ll, rr) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
dim(ll)
# [1] 3008   11
length(rr)
#[1] 3008
```

How can that be?

Comment: What is `dim(rr)`? Can you make your example reproducible?

Comment: Probably your `rr` is a vector (not a matrix) so it is horizontally oriented. Try to transpose it.

Comment: @Marta  WiIl work with a **vector** (no orientation in R). Not with a 1x3008 **matrix**.

Comment: Give also `dim(rr)` !

Comment: @jogo I would wager my family farm that it's `NULL`. :) (eh, Pascal already mentioned it in his answer)

Answer (score 6):

To illustrate Marta's comment:

```
set.seed(42)
ll <- matrix(rnorm(30),6, 5)
rr <- matrix(rnorm(6), 1, 6)
dim(ll)
# [1] 6 5
length(rr)
# [1] 6
cbind(ll, rr)
Error in cbind(ll, rr) : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)

cbind(ll, t(rr))
#            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
# [1,]  1.3709584  1.51152200 -1.3888607 -2.4404669  1.8951935  0.4554501
# [2,] -0.5646982 -0.09465904 -0.2787888  1.3201133 -0.4304691  0.7048373
# [3,]  0.3631284  2.01842371 -0.1333213 -0.3066386 -0.2572694  1.0351035
# [4,]  0.6328626 -0.06271410  0.6359504 -1.7813084 -1.7631631 -0.6089264
# [5,]  0.4042683  1.30486965 -0.2842529 -0.1719174  0.4600974  0.5049551
# [6,] -0.1061245  2.28664539 -2.6564554  1.2146747 -0.6399949  0.4554501
```

To illustrate Heroka's comment:

```
dim(ll)
# [1] 6 5
dim(rr)
# [1] 1 6
```

If `ll` is a matrix and `rr` a vector (R sense), i.e.

```
rr <- as.numeric(rr)
dim(rr)
# NULL
length(rr)
# 6
cbind(ll, rr)
#                                                                      rr
# [1,]  1.3709584  1.51152200 -1.3888607 -2.4404669  1.8951935  0.4554501
# [2,] -0.5646982 -0.09465904 -0.2787888  1.3201133 -0.4304691  0.7048373
# [3,]  0.3631284  2.01842371 -0.1333213 -0.3066386 -0.2572694  1.0351035
# [4,]  0.6328626 -0.06271410  0.6359504 -1.7813084 -1.7631631 -0.6089264
# [5,]  0.4042683  1.30486965 -0.2842529 -0.1719174  0.4600974  0.5049551
# [6,] -0.1061245  2.28664539 -2.6564554  1.2146747 -0.6399949  0.4554501
```

To get rid of column name:

```
cbind(ll, unname(rr))
```